# Is it legal to send large packages to someone by USPS without their consent?

Tags: united-states, mail

If I understand correctly, it is legal to send someone letters and small packages without their consent. Does this apply to large packages? Can I mail a refrigerator to a random address? (Don't worry; I'm not actually going to do this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

It is legal to do this within reason, although U.S.P.S. packages are [limited to 70 pounds](https://pe.usps.com/businessmail101?ViewName=MinMax#:%7E:text=USPS%20Retail%20Ground%20pieces%20may,mail%20have%20lower%20weight%20limits.) (which would be a very small refrigerator).

Generally speaking, however, you have no obligation to pay for a package that you did not ask to receive.

Comment: In my experience for letters and small packages, you can just mark the item refused and deposit it in a mail box and you'll never see it again. Don't know what would happen if you marked a 69 pound box refused and left it next to your mailbox.